# How to run a ruby script within bundler context?

Tags: ruby, bundle

I have a Ruby script called foo.rb, and I want to run it within the context of the bundler environment. How?

`bundle exec foo.rb` doesn't work, because exec expects a shell script.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Pass the script name to the `ruby` command:

```
bundle exec ruby [script_file_name]
```

If you also want the Rails environment:

```
bundle exec rails runner [script_file_name]
```

Comment: Wow, that was pretty obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @MichieldeMare It's like why everything is in the last place you look--because you stop looking ;)

Answer (score 7):

For instance, I wanted to use the same version of Rubocop as my Rails app and not the latest system one, so doing this in a script:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

# ...
```

Allowed me to use my app's version of rubocop.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a script that you can run in bundle context within a project, you can invoke Bundler programmatically. E.g., given a project:

```
foo
├── Gemfile
└── bar
    └── baz.rb
```

you can put the following at the top of `baz.rb` to give it access to the gems in the Gemfile:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)
require 'bundler/setup'

# ...etc.
```

With that, you can invoke the script directly without using `bundle exec`, and you also don't have to invoke it from within the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make it a script - add

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

to the start of the file, and make it executable. Then `bundle exec foo.rb` will work as expected.

(This is on unix or OSX - not sure about Windows)

See http://bundler.io/v1.15/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Loading

Also see https://coderwall.com/p/kfyzcw/execute-ruby-scripts-directly-without-bundler-exec for how to run ruby scripts with bundled dependencies, without needing `bundle exec`

Comment: If you are using RVM I believe this does not work. I think it is loading ruby in the global or local context, not in the RVM context. And you have to use `bundle exec ruby script_name` in order to have it run in the RVM context.