# I am trying to run a rails class file locally but what is the command to launch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, server

I am trying to run a scraper/spider class locally, or on a server, but what's the correct command to launch it?

For example, if the spider's name is newyorkhomes.rb and has the following:
module Spider
  module Feeds
    class NewYorkHomes < Spider::Feeds::Base

When I switch into the the directory containing the file, I tried to run the following: 
*load 'newyorkhomes.rb'* and 
*ruby 'newyorkhomes.rb'* but neither worked

bundle exec newyorkhomes.rb doesn't work either

should I execute it locally or on a server? I can change my directory into the file containing these scraper tasks on a server but the server doesn't support that many commands there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958594/how-to-run-a-ruby-script-within-bundler-context from Dave Newton

Answer (score 0):

No need for quotation marks. If I was in my `~/User/Desktop/` and wanted to run a file named `foo.rb`, I would simply run, `ruby foo.rb`.

Cheers.

Comment: I tried to execute it but then this is the message i received: pistilli.rb:3:in `<module:Feeds>': uninitialized constant Spider::Feeds::Base (NameError)
 from pistilli.rb:2:in `<module:Spider>'
 from pistilli.rb:1:in `<main>'